# how to stop WordPress cropping my post thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have a problem with my Post thumbnail being cropped in a dimensions i can't find anywhere in my css file or any of my theme's php files ..

- My thumbnail image suppose to be 164x150, but the result is a cropped thumbnail into 164x111 or 164x142 not sure exactly which.

this is my functions.php thumbnail code :

```
function novavideo_lite_get_post_no_thumbnail( $post ){

    global $post;

    // On récupère la liste des images attachées à l'article
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
        'exclude'        => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) );

    // On teste si on a des images ou non
    if ( $attachments ) {

        $attachments_tmp = array_values($attachments);
        $attachment = array_shift($attachments_tmp);

        $extention = explode( '.', $attachment->guid );
        $extention = end($extention);

        $attachment_url = str_replace( '.' . $extention, '-164x150.' . $extention, $attachment->guid );

        return '<img src="' . $attachment_url . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function novavideo_lite_theme_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );    
    add_image_size( 'thumb_site', '164', '150', false ); 
}
```

Notice that im already disabling cropping in last line ?

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'novavideo_lite_theme_support' );add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'novavideo_lite_rcd_remove_stock_image_sizes' ); function novavideo_lite_rcd_remove_stock_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
return array( 'thumb_site' );}function novavideo_lite_delete_thumb_function( $post_ID ) {   
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ):

    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    // On récupère la liste des images attachées à la vidéo
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    ) );
    // On teste si on a des images ou non
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

            //delete generated thumbs
            wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true );

            //delete original file
            $file_URI = str_replace($upload_dir['baseurl'], $upload_dir['basedir'], $attachment->guid);
            if( file_exists( $file_URI ) && !is_dir( $file_URI ) ){
                unlink( $file_URI );
            }
        }

    }

endif;}
```

i have also been using this code to automatically generate a thumbnail for post after publishing

```
add_filter('get_post_metadata', function($value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
if ($meta_key !== '_thumbnail_id' || $value) {
    return $value;
}

preg_match('~<img[^>]+wp-image-(\\d+)~', get_post_field('post_content', $object_id), $matches);
if ($matches) {
    return $matches[1];
}
return $value;}, 10, 4);
```

now when i open the Developers tool in chrome it is giving me this on a thumbnail 164 × 111 pixels (Natural: 210 × 142 pixels) 
apparently the thumb is being cropped as 164 × 111 and then stretched as 164 × 150 .. i found img[Attributes Style] giving the admissions 164 × 111 i disabled it with the code

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );   return $html;
```

but still the dimensions  164 × 111 pixels (Natural: 210 × 142 pixels) still show up and i believe this is what causing me this problem but can't find these diminutions anywhere in my theme files

this is my site link http://www.3dslab.com/

pls help

Answer (score 0):

i think it'll be easier to set the thumbnail dimensions with Thumbnail Size in

```
/wp-admin -> Settings -> Media
```

then uncheck "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" checkbox that is under Thumbnail Size.

then use the regular WP Post Thumbnail functions (such as get_the_post_thumbnail()) to place thumbnails on your page. The thumbnails will be thumbnails of featured images of the post you are displaying part of.

remember to include

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

in your functions.php file so featured images are activated on your posts and pages.

Note however that all your images should have same aspect ratio or the page your linked here will look rough and uneven.

Comment: Yeah i have already tried that , but no success , the /wp-admin -> Settings -> Media  method seems to have no effect on the thumb , while on the other hand the code in function.php file has full control on resizing it , also it seems that 210x142 is the default size in the theme so i gave up on changing it to 164x150 , but i do still have the cropping issue , while the images on my post are mostly squares , and my thumb is rectangular in dimensions , im still having a hard time identifying the problem , and im unchecking "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions " ..

Comment: Same problem here. What's going on with wordpress?!